# Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest' (but not a cross origin issue)

Tags: javascript

My draft website works in FireFox and IE and in Android Chrome but does not work in desktop Chrome. Desktop Chrome gives me this error

`"Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'"`.

Website URL: http://beyondproxima.appspot.com

URL loaded in XmlHttpRequest: http://beyondproxima.appspot.com/data.json

Failing in Chrome version: 56.0.2924.87 (Win 7)

This error is usually a cross origin scripting issue but I am trying to load a JSON file (synchronously) from the same domain, port etc...

Is Chrome blocking my request because I am doing an old-fashioned and deprecated synchronous request?

Comment: Works fine in 64bit chrome 56 windows 10 - but really, learn how to use asynchronous code now before it's not just deprecated :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was I was behind a zscaler network, so the location of the json resource did not match the one expected for the server. So the XmlHttpRequest failed. I did not want to enable CORS for my site, so I include a default set of data in the page for browsers unable to open the full data set via XmlHttpRequest.

So it was a cross origin issue after all.

Answer (score 5):

In my chrome your url is working fine and data is getting loaded.

Warning Message is there in chrome

> "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because
>   of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more
>   help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."

I think its just a browser issue and nothing else.. Just update your chrome.

[image]

Chrome 56.0

avoid making synchronous requests.
Instead of this.. 
`xmlHttp.open("GET", "http://google.com", false);`
use `true` in place of `false`.